# Как выбрать все теги и число связанных с ними статей одним запросом?

Tags: mysql, sql

Сейчас делаю через два запроса, используя цикл для нахождения количества прикреплённых статей для каждого тега.

```
define("SQL_QUERIES_TAGS_LIST", "
    SELECT *
    FROM `tags`
    ORDER BY `name`
");

define("SQL_QUERIES_TAGS_COUNT", "
    SELECT count(*) as `count`
    FROM `n_t`
    WHERE `n_t`.`id_tag` = ?
    GROUP BY `id_tag`
");
```

`n_t` - таблица связей с номерами тегов и статей.

**+ Должны быть возвращены и теги с числом 0, у которых нет связанных статей.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    tags.id,
    tags.name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(n_t.id) FROM n_t WHERE n_t.id_tag = tags.id) as count 
FROM tags 
ORDER BY tags.name
```

Comment: Спасибо, твой ответ навёл на мысли, но он выдаёт ошибку из-за синтаксиса. Вот то, что мне надо и это без ошибок, поправь свой ответ и я приму его как правильный. Дело было в очерёдности GROUP BY и ORDER BY.
SELECT `tags`.`id` as `id`, `tags`.`name` as `name`, count(*) as `count`
FROM `tags`, `n_t`
WHERE `tags`.`id` = `n_t`.`id_tag`
GROUP BY `n_t`.`id_tag`
ORDER BY `tags`.`name`

Comment: И ещё обнаружилась особенность, что не возвращаются теги без прикреплённых записей, а должно возвращаться с нолём.

Comment: @andreikorzhyts Обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо.
Я снова поправил ответ под себя:
SELECT `tags`.`id`, `tags`.`name`, (
              SELECT count(*)
              FROM `n_t`
              WHERE `n_t`.`id_tag` = `tags`.`id`
              ) as `count`
    FROM `tags` 
    ORDER BY `name`
Можешь снова исправить свой ответ для соответствия вопросу, если хочешь.
И если не трудно, то можешь пояснить немного вложенный выбор, не могу понять, как он влияет, как получается посчитать теги-сироты?

Comment: Это подзапрос, т.е. второй запрос внутри первого. В отличие от join он не требует обязательного наличия соответствия и может вернуть пустой результат.

Comment: Спасибо. Именно про эту разницу и не хватало для понимания.